# Create a Page Template Which Displays All Posts by Current User

Tags: posts, author, list

I would like to create a page template that will display all of the posts by the currently logged in user.  I managed to find an older thread which contained this code:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ):

global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$author_query = array('posts_per_page' => '-1','author' => $current_user->ID);
$author_posts = new WP_Query($author_query);
while($author_posts->have_posts()) : $author_posts->the_post();
?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>       
<?php           
endwhile;

else :

echo "not logged in";

endif;
```

however, the code does not appear to work (in fact, any page using the template which contains it simply won't load).

Comment: that code works fine for me, [enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and check for errors.

Comment: @Milo: Would you mind posting the complete code you're using for the page template that works?  I have a feeling I've made a coding error somewhere and I would like to compare.

Comment: I used your code and nothing else, except an opening `<?php` tag before it. if you've made an error, enabling debugging will tell you what it is and on what line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

```
    <?php if (is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>

        <?php
        //if a certain page, then display posts authored by the logged in user
        $page_title = 'Support History';
        if ( is_user_logged_in()  && is_page($page_title) ) {
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $args=array(
            'author' => $current_user->ID,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish, private',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'caller_get_posts'=> 1
        );
        $my_query = null;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo 'Your Support History';
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
        <?php
        endwhile;
        }
        wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
        }
        ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```